# How to restrict access to delete in laravel using sentry

Tags: laravel, cartalyst-sentry

Using Laravel 4 and Sentry. I have a CRUD admin system that managers and admins can access. I want managers to have access to all CRUD operations except for DELETE. I know that I can add a line such as

```
@if (Sentry::check())
```

in my view to ensure the user is logged in, but don't know how to check that they are an admin.

I have the following filter

```
Route::filter('auth.admin', function()
{

$user = Sentry::getUser();
$admin = Sentry::findGroupByName('Admins');

if (!$user->inGroup($admin)) return Redirect::to('admin/login');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy way:

```
if (Sentry::getUser()->isSuperUser())

// or
if (Sentry::hasPermission('superuser')) // or admin or whatever permission you want
```

or excplicitly:

```
if (Sentry::hasPermission('delete'))
```

Comment: You are a star. I updated my seeding of the groups table so that I have a superuser and can use your 1st two options.                       Sentry::getGroupProvider()->create(array(
         'name'        => 'Users',
         'permissions' => array(
             'admin' => 0,
             'users' => 1,
             'superuser' => 0,
         )));

  Sentry::getGroupProvider()->create(array(
         'name'        => 'Admins',
         'permissions' => array(
             'admin' => 1,
             'users' => 1,
             'superuser' => 1,
         )));